# How to use the "cache" in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab

I have created the following test pipeline in gitlab:

```
job1:
  stage: stage1
  rules:
    - if: $RUN != "run2"
      when: always
    - when: never
  script:
    - echo "Job stage1 updating file dates.txt"
    - date >> data/dates.txt
  cache:
    key: statusfiles
    paths:
      - data/dates.txt

job2:
  stage: stage2
  rules:
    - if: $RUN == "run2"
      when: always
  script:
    - echo "Running stage 2"
    - cat data/dates.txt
  cache:
    key: statusfiles
    paths:
      - data/dates.txt
```

where I want to use the "cache" feature of gitlab.

Here I first run `job1` which update the file `date.txt` and add an entry to this example files, so it contains two lines.

However, when I run a new pipeline with `job2` alone, the files contain only ONE line. The files seem to be the original, unmodified files.

How can I "upload" or "save" the files into the cache in `job1`, so I can use the updated file in a later run of `job2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test first if the section "[Share caches between jobs in the same branch](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#share-caches-between-jobs-in-the-same-branch)" is relevant.

> To have jobs in each branch use the same cache, define a cache with the key: >
>
> ```
> $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG:
> ```
>
> ```yaml
> cache:
>   key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
> ```
>
> This configuration prevents you from accidentally overwriting the cache.

In your case, from the [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/53481634#53481634), and from "[How archiving and extracting works](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#how-archiving-and-extracting-works)":

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - test

before_script:
  - echo "Hello"

job A:
  stage: build
    rules:
      - if: $RUN != "run3"
    when: always
      - when: never
  script:
    - mkdir -p data/
    - date > data/hello.txt
  cache:
    key: build-cache
    paths:
      - data/
  after_script:
    - echo "World"

  job B:
    stage: test
    rules:
      - if: $RUN == "run3"
    script:
      - cat data/hello.txt
    cache:
      key: build-cache
      paths:
        - data/
```

> By using a single runner on a single machine, you don’t have the issue where job `B` might execute on a runner different from job `A`.
>
> This setup guarantees the cache can be reused between stages.
>
> It only works if the execution goes from the build stage to the test stage in the same runner/machine. Otherwise, the [cache might not be available](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#cache-mismatch).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the syntax seems to be incorrect. I get an error "did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 1 column 1".

Comment: Ah found the problem. One tiny space was missing somewhere. The built-in check for the configuration is completely useless

Comment: https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator/

Comment: The pipeline does now run, but when I run `job2` after I have run `job1` the file is unchanged. Does not seem to work.

Comment: @Alex I have updated the answer from your comment in the discussion https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/53481634#53481634